# cglib compiler jdk compliance

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, aop, cglib

I'm getting a strange error on a colleague's box.  CGLib is auto-proxying a service class for spring AOP logging, and at runtime it says 'unresolved compilation error: must override a superclass method" on the fastclass by cglib proxy class.

In the offending class, I'm using @override annotations when I implement an interface, and I know that it's supported in jdk 1.6 but not 1.5.  CGLib is auto-proxying that implementation class.

However, it works fine on my box with jdk_1.6_17, but not on his with jdk_1.6_10.

However however, he can compile the project correctly using maven, which uses the same jdk.
Removing the @Override annotation fixes the runtime cglib error, but that's weird right?

What compiler does cglib use for its auto-proxying, and could this be a bug in jdk_1.6_10 or is there something else I'm missing?

Using spring 3.0.4, jboss 5.10, spring security 3.0.3

basically, the class implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService in spring-security.

The offending method signature:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication auth) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
```

UserDetails is a spring-security interface, and so is Authentication.

Comment: Can you show some source code of the method causing the problem? Is this method using generics or is it declared as returning a subtype of the overridden methods return type (covariance)?

Comment: added it, nothing like that, it's actually returning a custom implementation of UserDetails, but it's declared to be returning UserDetails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  I had explicity brought in cglib 2.2 into the pom.xml, and spring-flex was bringing in 2.1_03, which is from 2005.  For some reason, my box ended up using the new one, and my colleague's ended up using the old.

Anyone know why a particular one gets loaded first?

Comment: It's effectively random (i.e. there _is_ an algorithm, but it's not worth trying to work with it). The common solution, for cglib at least, seems to be to fork your own copy into your own namespace for your project.